# Proguard breaks parameterized constructor injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, proguard, roboguice, android-proguard

I set up a test project to see how I can use RoboGuice and Proguard with an injected parameterized constructor.

This is my proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keep class roboguice.** { *; }
-keep interface roboguice.** { *; }
-dontwarn roboguice.**

-keep class org.roboguice.** { *; }
-keep interface org.roboguice.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.roboguice.**

-keepattributes **

-keep class com.example.vladfatu.roboguicetest.application.TestModule

-keep class com.google.inject.Binder
-keep class com.google.inject.Module
-keep public class com.google.inject.** { *; }
 # keeps all fields and Constructors with @Inject
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
@com.google.inject.Inject <fields>;
@com.google.inject.Inject <init>(...);
}
```

This is my TestModule:

```
public class TestModule implements Module {

public TestModule() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void configure(Binder binder) {
    binder.bind(StateProvider.class).to(RoboTestStateProvider.class);
}

}
```

This is the StateProvider :

```
public interface StateProvider {

String getState();
}
```

This is the RoboTestStateProvider :

```
public class RoboTestStateProvider implements StateProvider {

private Context context;

@Inject
public RoboTestStateProvider(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public String getState() {
    return "State";
}

}
```

And this is the Application class:

```
public class RoboTestApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    RoboGuice.setUseAnnotationDatabases(false);
    configureInjection();
}

protected void configureInjection() {
    RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(this, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(this), new TestModule());
}
}
```

When it tries to create the Application Injector(in the Application class) it fails with this error:

> Could not find a suitable constructor in com.example.vladfatu.roboguicetest.monitor.RoboTestStateProvider. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.

I thought that the "@com.google.inject.Inject (...);" line from the proguard rules should have fixed this, but it hasn't. I even tried decompiling the apk to be sure that the @Inject annotation is there(before the constructor) and it is, but it still doesn't work.

Obviously, without Proguard this works fine...
The RoboGuice version I use is 3.0

Answer (score 0):

If you just want context you can either:

1. @Inject as a property
2. use `Provider<Context>` argument for the constructor

And include below in your proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keep class com.google.inject.Binder
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.google.inject.Inject <init>(...);
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @javax.inject.Inject <init>(...);
}
# There's no way to keep all @Observes methods, so use the ORn*Event convention to identify event handlers
-keepclassmembers class * {
    void *(**On*Event);
}
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keep public class roboguice.**
-keep class roboguice.** { *; }
-keep class org.roboguice.** { *; }
-keep public class javax.**
-keep public class javax.annotation.**
-keep public @interface javax.annotation.**
-keep public interface javax.annotation.**
-keep public class com.actionbarsherlock.**
-keep public class android.**
-keep public class android.** { *; }
-keep public class android.content.res.Resources.Theme
-keep public class android.content.res.Resources.Theme { *; }
-keep public class android.content.res.Resources
-keep public class android.content.res.Resources { *; }
-keep public class com.google.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.**
-keep public class android.support.**
-keep public interface android.support.**

#
# Added to get it to work
#

#-dontwarn roboguice.activity.RoboSherlockPreferenceActivity
-dontwarn com.actionbarsherlock.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn roboguice.activity.RoboMapActivity
-dontwarn roboguice.activity.SherlockAccountAuthenticatorActivity
-dontwarn javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
-dontwarn javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn javax.annotation.CheckForNull
-ignorewarnings
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I also received this error—even after doing the same things the op did—if any of the parameters of the constructor got obfuscated. (Even explicitly binding those classes in the RoboGuice `Module` configuration didn't help.)

But after I ensured that all the constructor parameter types also had ProGuard `-keepclassnames` exceptions, then ProGuard could find the constructor.

I guess that exception message is a little misleading in this case; or at least a little incomplete in that it should state that all constructor parameter types also need to be "found" by their original names.